# Formula to determine if X out of ANY Y cells have a certain value (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to add a column after "# of Time Attended" which will state "Y" or "N" if the student has earned the reward. The only criteria for earning the reward is ***that they are present 6 out of any 8 weeks***.

### Example:

**`NOTE: Checkmark = "P" & No checkmark = "A"`**

- If the student came for 5 weeks (*string* = "PPPPP"), missed 3 (*string* = "AAA"), and
  then came the 9th week (*string* = "P") they DO NOT get the reward (Total string = PPPPPAAAP).
- If the student came for 2 weeks (*string* = "PP"), missed 1 week (*string* = "A"), came for 4 (*string* = "PPPP"), and then missed again (*string* = "A") they WOULD get the reward (Total string = PPAPPPPA)

This needs to be a formula that anticipates any of the permutations that can occur, and I can't seem to figure it out. Any tips?

[image: Attendance Sheet]

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Here's a link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mI9ydTnevek_NNBynn_guuWxvkf7FFrsIcthKNfj6gA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: My solution doesn't work because I thought the question was about Excel - apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I take your question literally, I think you would need an offset formula to find the block of 8 consecutive cells which contains the largest number of attendances:

```
=MAX(COUNTIF(OFFSET(A1,0,COLUMN(A1:INDEX(A1:Q1,COLUMNS(A1:Q1)-7))-1,1,8),"P"))
```

Has to be entered as an array formula using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Both the students below have been absent most of the term, but the second one one does have six attendances in eight weeks starting from week 3:

[image]

**EDIT**

Apologies for misunderstanding - the equivalent Google Sheets formula should be

```
=ArrayFormula(max(len(substitute(mid(textjoin("",,B4:R4),row(indirect("A1:A"&COLUMNS(B4:R4)-7)),8),"A",""))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[One solution](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-specific-characters-in-a-range) would be to `substitute` all `P` and then count the length before and after the `substitute` and get the difference of both.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A1:A7)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:A7,"p","")))
```

or for a single cell

```
=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(A11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A11,"p","")))
```

With this there is no need to account for every permutation as it just counts all occuring characters that you insert.

You can switch the range to a single cell, if the string, which needs to get checked is in one cell.

[image]

If the cells just contain "P" or "A", then even `COUNTIF(A1:A7;"P")` would be sufficient

Comment: If I understand this correctly, this gets me the number of times a student is absent or present but it doesn't tell me if out of any 8 classes, the student was there for 6 of them.